# Is there a better way than SQL strings in Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, string

I have a SQL code with CTEs and `case` statements, approx 700 lines and 90 fields output.

I am struggling to convert it to a VBA sqlstring. I have overcome the "Too many line continuations" but now encounter 'Statement too Complex'. This is after cleaning the query and using a converter tool and breaking it down into chunks.

The SQL string is then used to copy from recordset and paste in worksheet.

I have successfully done this method before, but not on such a complex query. I only need VBA for the user to essentially change an id in the `where` clause.

Is there a better way than SQL strings to get desired effect as it is an absolute pain in the backside and difficult to debug and amend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed long and complex sql queries into Excel VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48100470/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to define a large vba string - i.e. heredoc equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3671308/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL too long for String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9764234/11683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view using that query and then use a very simple query in VBA to query the view.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila then get someone who has access to do it for you. If your place has a DBA, and that DBA is doing their job, then they'll be VERY happy for you to remove arbitrary stringified SQL queries from your code. If you need parameters, have a stored procedure made instead, and use an `ADODB.Command` to run it securely, with `ADODB.Parameter` objects for the values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100915/1188513).

Comment: Creating a View is definitely the solution. It simplifies everything.